# SQL SERVER - no me deja insertar mas de 36633 caracteres en un campo TEXT

Tags: sql-server

Buen día 
quisiera saber que podría hacer lo que lo limita cuando inserto un párrafo con mas de 36633 caracteres.

Lo inserto a traves sql managment studio y se corta el texto tambien lo probé a través c# pensando que pueda ser un limite del sql managment studio y lo inserta igual ,cuando select me da siempree 36644(los cuento y también uso DATALENGTH)

PUSE VARCHAR(MAX) Y PASA LO MISMO.

La versión SQL SERVER 2012.

Comment: Por favor, comparte el código que estás usando. Eso nos dará una mejor idea de donde puede estar el problema. También es recomendable que dejes de utilizar TEXT y en vez de eso utilices VARCHAR(MAX)

Comment: @LuisCazares Hola,
Codigo de sql ? 
insert into tabla_c(1,'sala_lab','asd asd asd '); , puedes usar esto para generar texto https://getlorem.com/es/  , tambien usé varchar(max)

Comment: El ejemplo lo puedo generar yo, lo que necesitamos es ver el código que estás usando para ver en que momento se trunca el texto.

Comment: Solo pruebalo en el sql managment , no es necesario el c#.
Lo hago en sql managmente y me pasa eso ,igual que c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí hay una posibilidad (de varias) que pueden existir. Lo más probable es que sea un caso de conversión implicita que no alcanzamos a ver.

```
CREATE TABLE TextoLargo( MiTexto VARCHAR(MAX));

INSERT INTO TextoLargo
SELECT REPLICATE('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit faucibus, dis placerat integer fringilla fusce non potenti ante duis. ', 1005)
UNION ALL
SELECT REPLICATE(CAST('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit faucibus, dis placerat integer fringilla fusce non potenti ante duis. ' AS varchar(MAX)), 1005);

SELECT DATALENGTH( MiTexto)
FROM TextoLargo;

DROP TABLE TextoLargo;
```

En la primer opción, se aprecia que se trunca por ser un varchar de longitud normal, mientras que en la segunda se mantiene el tipo de dato largo.